# Is it possible in C to create a file scope object whose address may not be computed?

Tags: c

What I want is to ensure that file scope variables (in my program) can not be modified from outside the file. So I declare them as 'static' to preclude external linkage. But I also want to make sure that this variable can not be modified via pointers.

I want something similar to the 'register' storage class, in that

> the address of any part of an object declared with storage-class
>   specifier register cannot be computed, either explicitly (by use of
>   the unary & operator) or implicitly (by converting an array name to a
>   pointer).

but without the limitations of the 'register' keyword (can not be used on file scope variables, arrays declared as register can not be indexed).

That is,

```
<new-keyword> int array[SIZE] = {0};

int a = array[0]; /* should be valid */
int *p = array; /* should be INVALID */
p = &array[3]; /* should be INVALID */
```

What is the best way to go about achieving this goal?

*Why do I desire such a feature?*
The usage scenario is that this file will be modified by many people in the future even when I can not personally overview all modifications. I want to preclude as many potential bugs as possible. In this case I want to make sure that variables meant to be 'private' to the module will remain so without having to depend just on documentation and/or discipline

Comment: I don't think so as anything you store do have an address. However, you could "hide" the address : make a kind of virtual address or apply a mask to get the "real" address.

Comment: IMO: if a pointer to the array can be formed, then the address of the array can be calculated.  This is because a statement like: array[0] is actually requesting the contents of the integer at (address of array)+(0*sizeof(int))

Comment: a const is in readonly memory, with an address, so its' address can be calculated, however, the compiler will inhibit any writes, thereby making this line: *p = &array[3]; /* should be INVALID */ raise an compile error or runtime seg fault event.

Comment: everything in c is in the form of bit string. how could you achieve that if something is in the memory.

Comment: @user3629249, HuStmpHrrr - Right. The unaddressability (sic) of variables (which occupy addressable memory) is to be enforced by the compiler not necessarily by the machine.

Comment: @barakmanos - The variables aren't constant, they are modifiable by functions in the file.

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't think you can do so, at least not cleanly. But I also fail to understand your usage case fully.

If your object is `static`, nobody knows its name outside of your module. So nobody can use `&` to take its address.

If you need to expose it, and don't want other parts of the program modifying it, write a function that exposes it as a constant pointer:

```
static int array[SIZE];

const int * get_array(void)
{
  return array;
}
```

Then compile with warnings. If somebody casts away the `const`, it's their problem.

Comment: i think exposing `const int *arrayAlias=array;` should be enough to do the trick.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr Sure, but a function is cleaner than a global variable shared across modules, in my opinion.

Comment: I don't want to expose it, in fact I want to ensure that there is absolutely no way a foreign module can alter data which belongs to 'my' module. A foreign module can alter data of this module a) if it has access to it via 'extern' or b) it has access to it via a pointer to the variable (received as a function parameter).

I preclude (a) by using the keyword 'static', but I can not preclude (b). I can only avoid it by team discipline assisted by documentation.

Comment: The usage scenario is that this file will be modified by many people in the future even when I can not personally overview all modifications. I want to preclude as many potential bugs as possible. In this case I want to make sure that variables meant to be 'private' to the module will remain so without having to depend just on documentation and/or discipline.

Comment: *No, I don't think you can do so, at least not cleanly.* - I kinda came to that conclusion myself after going through the C specification. I was hoping that I missed something or that someone else has achieved something similar, even if through contrived means.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are concerned with security issues, here are a few things to consider:

1. The purpose of `register` keyword was to recommend the compiler to keep that variable in a register, as it will be intensively used. As the registers don't have a memory address, it is impossible to get it (although this wasn't the primary purpose of this keyword; it is merely a side-effect). As compilers got better at generating efficient code, this is not needed any more.
2. Even if you could make all objects in your code "addess-proof" (impossible to get their address), the program will still not be 100% safe. Those objects are still stored in memory, which is still visible. By analysing the binary files, using debuggers, analysing the memory map and so on, one could find out those memory addresses.
3. This is not a good practice. In order for someone to get the variable of an object in a module, that object must be global, which is bad. So you should worry about having global variables, not about their visibility. [Here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil) you can find more details about why is it bad to have variables in the global scope.
4. As a semi-solution to your "problem", you can declare them const static. This way they cannot be accessed from outside the module and if it happens, no one can change their value.

Comment: I am not looking for security from wilfully malevolent hackers, I am looking for protection from inadvertent mistakes made by people maintaining this module down the line.

Comment: In this case, you should use a good coding standard. If you modularise your code correctly and make your modules orthogonal, you don't need some "extra protection".